# Run my Mac command "chsh -s /usr/local/bin/false" and can't log in to my account again

Tags: macos, unix

I really messed up!
Since I ran my Mac with the command below

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/false
```

Several minutes later, I noticed my Mac logged out by itself.
So, I tried to log back in by clicking 'change user'
But I can't see my administer account there.

I guess 'false' is not a loggin-able shell, that's why my account is hidden.

I'm trying to change my shell with Terminal.app on recovery mode or single-user-mode (but both are read-only).

So right now, I want to know if there's any solutions that might be able to fix this problem.

Comment: ask it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now!

Comment: ow! maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/39400/what-chsh-did-when-i-type-chsh-s-shell-and-how-to-go-back-to-previous-shell) could help? (but you say you don't see admin...)

Comment: Thank you again! But I can see just guest user. I'll try sudo from guest user.

Comment: I don't have mac but you probably [can't `sudo` as guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362528/sudo-not-available-in-guest-login).

Comment: That's right. But I've got new helpful hint at another site you told me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294574/run-my-mac-command-chsh-s-usr-local-bin-false-and-cant-log-in-to-my-account. thank you!